# No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlserver:VAIO:1434;databaseName=MyDB

Tags: sql, sqlexception, rfid

This is my code, I added sqljdbc4.jar, im using sql ms server ..

```
try
{
    Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
    System.out.println("Loaded");


    Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver:VAIO:1434;databaseName=MyDB");
    System.out.println("started");
    PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO Tag_Info (TagNo, LastSeenTime) VALUES ('"+ID+"','"+Last+"')");
    stmt.executeUpdate();
    System.out.println("Data Inserted");
    connection.close();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
    System.err.println("Problem Connecting!");
}
```

this is the error message:

> ```
> java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlserver:VAIO:1434;databaseName=MyDB
>   at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:689)
> Loaded
>   at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:270)
>   at com.alien.enterpriseRFID.examples.AlienClass1ReaderTest.<init>(AlienClass1ReaderTest.java:59)
>   at com.alien.enterpriseRFID.examples.AlienClass1ReaderTest.main(AlienClass1ReaderTest.java:91)
> Problem Connecting!
> ```

Comment: May depend on the version of Java you are using.  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378422.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Use "//" in the connection string:

```
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://VAIO:1434;databaseName=MyDB");
```

And while it is good practice to change the default SQL Server port, the default is 1433.  1434 is for UDP.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I already tried to add "//" it gave me another error says:"The TCP/IP connection to the host VAIO, port 1433 has failed. Error: "Connection refused: connect."

Comment: I see.  Try adding user/pw or stop your firewall.  Likely one or the other, or both.  "jdbc:sqlserver://VAIO:1434;databaseName=MyDB;user=MyUserName;password=*****;"